# How to define a custom similarity measure

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, similarity

I need some help defining a custom similarity measure.

I have a dataset whose elements are defined by 4 attributes. 
As an example, consider the following two items:

```
Element 1:

A1: "R1", "R3", "R4", "R7"
A2: "H1"
A3  "F1", "F2"
A4  "aaa" "bbb"


Element 2:

A1: "R1", "R2"
A2: "H1"
A3  "F1", "F2"
A4  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff"
```

I have to implement a similarity measure which should satisfies the following conditions:

1 - If A2 value is the same, the two elements must belong to the same cluster

2 - If two elements have at least one common value on A4, the who elements must belong to the same cluster.

I need to use a sort of weighted Jaccard measure. Is it mathematically correct to define a similarity measure that sums the jaccard distance of each attribute and then to add a sort of high weigth if condition 1 and 2 are satisfied for A2 and A4?

If so, how can I transform the similarity matrix into a distance matrix?

Comment: `Is it mathematically correct to define ... ` well that's certainly not a programming question. There's a couple of things a transformation must fulfill to be a metric. You can look it up, then you have to check... Probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Distance = 1 - similarity.  This is a common characteristic.

(2) Summing the distances of the attributes is valid, although you may wish to scale it back to the [0, 1] range.

(3) Putting a high weight is not correct for what you've described.  If the A2 or A4 values show a match, simply set the distance to 0.  The clustering is a *requirement*, not merely strong advice.  Is there some other semantic to your distance function, that you didn't want to take this route?

FYI, the basics for being a topological metric's distance function, D are:

```
D(a, a) = 0
D(a,b) = D(b,a)
D(a,b) + D(b,c) >= D(a,c)
```

Comment: Thank you Prune for all the good hints :)
Maybe it's better to consider the clustering condition as a very strong advice. If I set the distance to 0, what I'll miss is the distance information about all the others attributes.

Even if these attributes have a small weight, for me it's important to save these differences.

What about normalizing the other attributes distance into a range of [0 - 0.5] and giving 0.25 for A2 and 0.25 for A4?
I know that if only A2 and A4 are matched will cause some problems, but basing on the nature of the elements that I'm working with it's a very rare condition.

Comment: The suggested metric still doesn't work in general; your requirements insist that *either* A2 or A4 matching *must* have precedence over any other factors, combined.  You could give them each 0.34 and leave 0.32 for the remainder, canting the clustering algorithm with a threshold of 0.34 or less.

One problem here is that you're trying to handle three disjoint requirements -- two boolean and one gradient -- with a single gradient metric.  Are you also writing your own clustering algorithm?  You could also handle the boolean requirements there with a pair, such as (True, 0.28).